# Why cannot I use primitive as mutex of syncronized section?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, primitive, critical-section

I noticed interesting(surprising for me) behaviour:

```
public void m(){
        int primitive=1;
        synchronized (primitive) {

        }
    }
```

this code generates following:

```
int is not a valid type's argument for the synchronized statement
```

Can you explain why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What primitive is used to implement the synchronized keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684530/what-primitive-is-used-to-implement-the-synchronized-keyword)

Comment: because it takes an object.

Comment: To be specific how that duplicate answers the question: `monitorenter` takes an object. Primitives are not objects. JVM has no way to synchronize on them.

Comment: That duplicate links to a very good page: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076971/java-concurrency/how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization.html

Comment: @hyde it is absolutely another question

Comment: @Scary Wombat but I could not watch signature of input arguments

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: quote: Unlike synchronized methods, synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock:

Comment: It might not be clear to some readers, so I'll augment above quote of @ScaryWombat by adding that synchronized methods also must have an object to synchronize on (`this` or the class object), it's just implicitly specified by method type (instance or static method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A primitive is just a bare value, nothing else.  This is the whole point of a primitive, it is as simple as possible.  Adding a lock is an overhead, i.e. it add 4 bytes, and the Object's entire header can be 16 bytes.

Only Objects have support for methods and synchronized.

The reason it matters is that a `byte` uses one byte, but a `Byte` which can be locked uses 16 to 24 bytes.  If you have a buffer with millions of these, having support for a lock seems like a waste if you don't need it.

BTW, you should never lock on a local or mutable variable unless you like confusion.